# How to create Top AppBar similar to built-in apps in Windows 8.1?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, appbar

The built-in Windows 8.1 apps like **Sports**, **Travel**, etc. use cool top multi-level AppBar. It almost looks like it's some kind of standard UserControl to be used in any app, but I haven't  found any guide, how to add it simply in my app as well.
Is this really some kind of generic appbar, or custom AppBar used only in Microsoft apps? The basic CommandBar has no such styling I am aware of.

[image: Top AppBar]

Answer (score 0):

There is AppBar control in WP 8.1 but you may need to set its layout and style. But you can start with default styling. Consider the sample of app bar below where I have added few primary command and one secondary command

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,258,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Demo AppBar" FontSize="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="314"/>

    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Save"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="Cancel"/>
                <AppBarSeparator />
                <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add New" />
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Label="About">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/Logo.scale-100.png" />
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

You may like to have a look at [Windows 8.1 app bar sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-AppBar-control-sample-2aa1cbb4)

Comment: I've actually found out that the NavBar component used in these apps is only available for HTML Windows 8.1 apps, but maybe we'll see port of this control in Callisto library. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-NavBar-control-sample-4472d92a

Answer (score 0):

Still trying it out but I guess this is the solution to make it look like the built in apps:
[Tutorial for a Top AppBar / NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081965/tutorial-for-a-top-appbar-navigationbar/24084970#24084970)

You can place any GUI-elements you wish inside opf an "AppBar", even AppBars that will roll out on rightclick are possible. So you have to rightclick it 2 times to get all menus.

It looks all the same because MS did them all in it's own studio. I don't think there are sources anywhere because the functionality is possible but the looks should differ. They explicitely advice to design the AppBar differently to make an awesome app in their style guide.